# dropping a column from a queryset

Tags: python, django, ply

I'm not so sure if this is a question, or a feature request to Django, or maybe I'm making things unnecessarily complicated.  I'm writing a user interface where I let the user write queries, which I convert into creation, modification, and combination of Django query sets.

the software uses `ply`, (writing into `p[0]` amounts to `return`) and here you have a few excerpts of the grammar:

here I'm converting things looking like words, or words separated with dots, into something that django will recognize.

```py
def p_field_fieldname(p):
    'field : fieldname'
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_field_dot_fieldname(p):
    'field : field DOT fieldname'
    p[0] = '{}__{}'.format(p[1], p[3])
```

implementing the test for inclusion in a list (I'm using a global `search_domain`, which is obviously causing trouble, but this is not the point here).

```py
def p_bfactor_list_comprehension(p):
    'bfactor : field IN LBRACKET valuelist RBRACKET'
    p[0] = search_domain.objects.filter(**{'{}__in'.format(p[1]): p[4]})
```

combining `bfactor` tokens.

```py
def p_bterm_bfactor(p):
    'bterm : bfactor'
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_expression_or_bterm(p):
    'expression : expression OR bterm'
    p[0] = p[1].union(p[3])

def p_bterm_and_bfactor(p):
    'bterm : bterm AND bfactor'
    p[0] = p[1].intersection(p[3])
```

so far, so good.  the problem I'm having is when I introduced aggregate functions, in combination with other queries, letting the user write things like:

`taxon where rank.id>=17 and count(verifications)=0`

I'm implementing the `count`, I did that by adding an extra column and testing on it, but then I've been having a hard time trying to intersect the two query sets, results of the two clauses `count(verifications)=0` and `rank.id>=17`.

I tried `defer` but I did not manage to remove the column **after** it was used.

in the end, I wrote this terribly ugly solution,

```py
def p_bfactor_aggregate_comparison(p):
    'bfactor : aggregate LPAREN field RPAREN operator value'
    from django.db.models import Count, Sum  # adding field to qs
    _, aggregate, _, field, _, operator, value = p
    f = {'count': Count, 'sum': Sum}[aggregate]
    q = search_domain.objects.annotate(temp_field=f(field))
    matching = set(i['id'] 
        for i in q.filter(**{'temp_field__{}'.format(operator): value})
                  .values('id'))
    p[0] = search_domain.objects.filter(id__in=matching)
```

my other best guess (more precisely, my hope it would work) was:

```py
def p_bfactor_aggregate_comparison(p):
    'bfactor : aggregate LPAREN field RPAREN operator value'
    from django.db.models import Count, Sum  # adding field to qs
    _, aggregate, _, field, _, operator, value = p
    f = {'count': Count, 'sum': Sum}[aggregate]
    q = search_domain.objects.annotate(temp_field=f(field))
    p[0] = q.filter(**{'temp_field__{}'.format(operator): value}
        ).WHATEVERWORKS('temp_field')
```

unfortunately however, I did not find the `WHATEVERWORKS` function.

if I don't remove that column, as soon as the parser meets the AND or OR productions, it gives the error `django.db.utils.OperationalError: SELECTs to the left and right of INTERSECT do not have the same number of result columns`.

from 2012 to early this year, I've been using SQLAlchemy, where I already implemented something very similar to this.  using Django, I am getting the impression I'm behind an overly smart abstraction layer.